# How to do a row-specific iterative calculation as many times as the value of a specific variable the row has?

Tags: r, iteration, row, calculation

I have a monthly financial data. I want to do some iterative calculation for each individual row. I have a variable REMCOUPS, and each row has an integer value for REMCOUPS.

Thus, for each row, I want to do the iteration for the number of times indicated by the value of REMCOUPS.

My codes run as follows:

```
for(i in 1:REMCOUPS){ Price <- 0 
  if(i!=REMCOUPS)Price <- Price + (Bonds_2016_2020B$COUPON/2)/(1+(as.numeric(Bonds_2016_2020B$YIELD1.y/2))^i)  
  else Price <- Price + (Bonds_2016_2020B$COUPON/2)/(1+(as.numeric(Bonds_2016_2020B$YIELD1.y/2))^i)
  + 100/(1+(as.numeric(Bonds_2016_2020B$YIELD1.y/2))^i)
}
```

Bonds_2016_2020B is my dataset name. For each row, I want to do an interactive calculation starting from Price=0 and adding (COUPON/2)/(1+YIELD)^1, (COUPON/2)/(1+YIELD)^2 ... (COUPON/2)/(1+YIELD)^(the value-1 of REMCOUP), and finally, when iteration reaches REMCOUP times, I add
(COUPON/2)/(1+YIELD)^(the value of REMCOUP) and 100/(1+YIELD)^(the value of REMCOUP).

As I ran my codes, my first error was:

Error in REMCOUPS : object 'REMCOUPS' not found

How can I achieve this?

### Update

Here is further information.

- REMCOUPS or REMCOUPS1 is the number of remaining coupons.
- CUSIP is the bond identifier.

So, for each month, DATE, I am going to calculate the present value of all the remaining future cash flows. The number of future cash flows is REMCOUPS (or REMCOUPS1).

[image: What my dataset looks like]

Thus, looking at the picture, let's suppose we are going to calculate the present value of a Bond(cusip id: 00130HBT1) at 2018-05-31, which has 10 remaining cash flows (REMCOUPS1). Then, the formula is:

The present Value of that bond at 2018-05-31 = (Cash flow)/(1+YIELD)^1 + (Cash flow)/(1+YIELD)^2 + ... + (Cash flow)/(1+YIELD)^REMCOUP1  +  100/(1+YIELD)^REMCOUP1

100/(1+YIELD)^REMCOUP1, this is the final payment of the bond's written price.

Since REMCOUPS1 is 10 in this case, I should calculate and add up 10 items in the above (11 items including the final bond's price).

The main problem for me is that since I am a beginner in R coming from SAS, I am not understanding the logic of R yet.

Comment: Please follow the post-signup intro posts and tutorials to learn how to improve the quality of your question: properly format your code to make it readable, include sample data, etc. Your code snippet does not include any reference to `REMCOUPS1` so the error seems to originate from elsewhere in your script.

Comment: Also see [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: I see you edited your post; the error message now seems to refer to `REMCOUPS` (previously `REMCOUPS1`). What kind of object is `REMCOUPS`? Is it a vector? A `data.frame`? I am not following your statement *"I have a variable REMCOUPS, and each row has an integer value for REMCOUPS."* Each row *of what*? Please add representative minimal sample data (e.g. use `dput` and then include the output as code text in your post).

Comment: I'm guessing this is muni bonds based on the semiannual coupons? Can you please share an example of source data (ideally using `dput(YOUR_TABLE)` so we can reproduce it in the form you have it, and describe what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hey guys, thank you so much! I edited my main text by overwriting further clarifications. Please check it out and help me;;

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidyverse approach. I'm understanding these to be bonds which pay out semiannually.

First, here's three made-up bonds -- a premium bond, a par bond, and a discount bond.

```
Bonds_2016_2020B <- data.frame(BOND = 1:3,
                               COUPON = c(0.04, 0.06, 0.08),
                               YIELD1 = c(0.03, 0.06, 0.10),
                               REMCOUPS = 5:7)
```

Now, I'll make a line for each coupon payment, calculate the discount rate at that time, and apply that discount to any coupon or principal payments due. The price is the sum of those discounted cash flows.

```
library(tidyverse)
Bonds_2016_2020B %>%
  
  # uncount, from the tidyr package in tidyverse, will copy each row REMCOUPS times
  uncount(REMCOUPS, .id = "COUPNUM", .remove = FALSE) %>%
  
  # each payment of coupon or principal will be discounted based on the # of semiannual periods. I'm assuming the first payment is 6 months away.
  mutate(discount   = 1/ ((1+YIELD1/2)^(COUPNUM)),
         COUP_disc  = discount * COUPON/2,
         PRINC_disc = discount * if_else(COUPNUM == REMCOUPS, 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(BOND) %>%
  summarize(price = 100*sum(COUP_disc + PRINC_disc)) %>%
  mutate(price_showing_more_digits = format(price, nsmall = 6))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   BOND price price_showing_more_digits
* <int> <dbl> <chr>                    
1     1 102.  "102.391322"             
2     2 100.  "100.000000"             
3     3  94.2 " 94.213627"
```

BTW, this matches exactly my check in Excel:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your codes. When I ran them, however, I get the error Error in rep(seq_nrow(data), w) : invalid 'times' argument. How should I deal with it?

Comment: Mr. Spring, now it works, after removing all NAs.